# Docker-compose: Build arguments?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run `docker-compose` while using the newish SSH forwarding argument: `docker build --ssh default .`, for example. Is there a way to pass the `--ssh` flag to the build process?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/9325